# C: int or unsigned int which type I used for pointer increasement

Tags: c, pointers, integer, pointer-arithmetic

For this situation:

```
int arr[] = {0, 1, 2};
void func (int* arr_in){
  int offset_0 = 0;
  int offset_1 = 1;
  int offset_2 = 2;
  printf("%d\n", *(arr_in + offset_0) );
  printf("%d\n", *(arr_in + offset_1) );
  printf("%d\n", *(arr_in + offset_2) );
}
```

The compiler will not complain whether the  I use is `int` or `unsigned`.

Two of results also seems correctly.

```sh
$ clang test.c -Wall -o test
```

I refer to the chapter §6.5.6/8 in the draft C11:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
> result has the type of the pointer operand.

In the draft, there is no mention of *"integer"* which is (signed)`int` or `unsigned`.

So both there can be used for *pointer operand* on all platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the C Standard carefully.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 17 **The type char, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the
> enumerated types are collectively called integer types.** The integer
> and real floating types are collectively called real types.

and now you can reread your quote from the C Standard

> When an expression that has **integer type** is added to or subtracted
> from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand.

So you may use even the type `char` that is neither signed or unsigned integer type.

Answer (score 5):

In this context "an expression that has integer type" refers to *any* integer type, e.g. `signed` or `unsigned` `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long`, as well as any other integer types defined by the implementation.

So you can safely use arguments of type `int` or `unsigned int` with a pointer, provided the resulting pointer still points to the same object or array.

Comment: As a curiosity for the OP (and others) it's valid to use a *negative* index (or offset). The same provisions regarding the resulting pointer must still hold.

Answer (score 1):

`int = 1` and `unsigned int = 1` are same thing, `int = -1` and `ungisned int = -1` and not the same thing.. If you use 1, 2 and 3, the answer is yes you can "call" it `int`, `unsigned int` or whatever you want. If you want the offset to be negative for example you can't use `unsigned int`, or if you want the offset to be larger then `2^31`, then you can't use `unsigned int`.

Comment: Whether the `int` bound is 2^31−1 (not 2^31) or not is implementation-defined.